# Differences between Kim and Marshmallow python frameworks

Tags: python, json, rest, serialization, frameworks

In looking into `serialisation` (or `encoding` or `marshalling`) and `deserialisation` (`decoding`, `unmarshalling`), I came across [kim](https://kim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) and [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as possible python framework to achieve this goal.

From their description alone I could not grasp the main differences and pros/cons in respect to their choice, and so I do not know which one would be the best choice.

Is their aim completely overlapping, and the choice is a matter of developer preferences or do they cover different functionalities and so they can be used in combination?

Comment: Hi, did you find out ? 
I'm looking for a good solution for object-mapping that supports polymorphism (from JSON to dynamic object type and back).

Comment: nope, still an open debate!

Comment: Maybe worth checking that: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-oneofschema